# Postinstall, rvm(ruby version manager) without root access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am trying to use RVM, ("[ruby version manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com)") and after the source installation, I need to add rvm command into my profile.

I added following code to the `$HOME/.profile`  file but it does not seem to work.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

So I just manually typed below for temporary addition of rvm command, but it does not seem to work. I get Missing name for redirect error like below.

```
>>source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
Missing name for redirect.
```

How can I resolve this problem? BTW, I do not have root access, and my linux is a redhat system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a description of how [Bash reads its startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files). I think you want to use either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

Once you've added the line to one of those files you'll need to open a new terminal window. Type `echo $PATH` and you should see RVM's path initialization at the start of it. Type `which ruby` and it should point to one in your `~/.rvm` path. Type `rvm list` and it should show the Rubies under its control.

Also, be sure to run `rvm get head` regularly to install the most recent version of rvm as the author updates it often.